# Как развернуть старый проект? Ошибка npm install

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, node-modules

Пытаюсь по курсу сделать проект, но не получается.
Если это старый проект, то он должен же разворачиваться даже если старые версии пакетов, когда-то же работало! В моем случае папка node_modules появляется и сразу исчезает, выходят следующие ошибки(скрины). Как это дело всё исправить? Почему ошибка?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: Когда-то работало, но явно на более молодой версии `node.js` и `npm`.

Comment: Как минимум: "Gulp 3.9.1 will work with Node 8 (latest noded 8 is 8.17.0) and with nothing newer."

Comment: То есть нужно откатить npm и node? Как это безболезненно сделать сейчас? Хочу запустить, а потом вернуть всё обратно после прохождения курса...

Comment: [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)